# jQuery document ready function not called when page accessed from link in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a coffeescript file `shows.js.coffee` that is in my `assets/javascripts folder`. It contains code to make a checkbox toggle two divs on the page.

If I click a link that takes me to the page the jQuery never gets called. The two divs appear loaded and clicking on the checkbox does nothing.

Once I am on the page if I hit reload, or if I just go to `localhost:3000/shows/new` in my browser the jQuery is loaded and the divs hide and the checkbox toggles them.

If I turn turbolinks off the problem goes away. Is there something I need to be doing differently to have turbolinks and still have my jQuery work?

Here is my `shows.js.coffee`

```
$('.shows.new').ready( ->
  $(document).ready( ->
    if(not $('#show_dinner_served').is(':checked'))
      console.log 'Checked'
      $('.dinner_starts').hide()
      $('.dinner_ends').hide()
  )

  $(document).ready( ->
    $('#show_dinner_served').click( ->
      $('.dinner_starts').toggle()
      $('.dinner_ends').toggle()
    )
  )
)
```

And my `application.js`

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I think its because you are using TurboLinks.

Comment: Why do you have `$(document).ready...` inside `$('.shows.new').ready...`.  How is `$('.shows.new').ready...` triggered?  Is this element with classes `shows` and `new` above the DOM `document`?  I think you should revisit your javascript and place `$('.shows.new').ready` inside `$(document).ready...`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact turbolinks breaks some events. It is described in detail on their [github page (Events)](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) and a well known problem. Try using the `jquery-turbolinks` gem. You can find it [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When enabled, TurboLinked pages will not load completely so the jqyery's `document.ready()` will not work as expected. Instead turbolink provides a trigger, you can use that instead of document ready.

**Example -**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
    // CODE
});
```